# Convert object to JSON omitting certain (private) properties

Tags: javascript, json

I've been using dean edwards base.js (http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/03/base/)  to organise my program into objects ( base.js is amazing btw, if you havent used it before !).Anyway, my question is generic and you don't have to know base.js to know my answer.

I have a property  in one of my objects called `ref` which is a reference to a DOM element, and this object is meant to be saved as JSON using `JSON.stringify`, but as you can imagine since DOM elements are circular structure, I won't be able to convert the object into JSON.

Now to get around this problem I have a method called `html()` which is meant to return the `ref` property, but I need to have `ref` as a private property which is only accessible from within the object, and hence won't be sent to `stringify`.

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: I don't follow. Can you show some before/after results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably know that you cannot have private properties in JavaScript.

Interestingly, if you pass an object to `JSON.stringify` which has a method `toJSON`, `JSON.stringify` will automatically call that method to get a JSONable representation of that object. So all you have to do is implement this method.

For example you can create a shallow copy of the object which only contains the properties you want to copy:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var copy = {},
        exclude = {ref: 1};
    for (var prop in this) {
        if (!exclude[prop]) {
            copy[prop] = this[prop];
        }
    }
    return copy;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SRa9p/)

Another way would be to [use a custom replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter), but it might be more difficult to control which `ref` to exclude and which one to keep (if different objects have `ref` properties):

```
JSON.stringify(someInstance, function(key, value) {
     if(key !== 'ref') {
         return value;
     }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SRa9p/1/)

Comment: this is a great answer, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

here is sample to to set variable visibility

```
function Obj(){
       this.ref = 'public property'; // this property is public from within the object

       var ref = 'private proerty'; // this property is private.

       var self = this;

        this.showRef = function(){
            alert(ref);
            alert(self.ref);
        };
    }

var obj = new Obj();
obj.showRef();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the problem with your solution is that the private property defined in that way is not accessible by other methods in the same object, which is what I need