# How to exclude an object's id property before or during $.toJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm writing a custom REST adapter for ember-data users with a django rest framework app and need to build a JSON string to do POST/PUT. The only problem is I can't seem to chain another jQuery method after the `$.toJSON` that removes this.

So far I have an `ember.js` object that I plan to extract each property from, except my django app doesn't want the `id` to go along with the HTTP POST

I can get a legit string like so

```
$.param(record.toJSON());
```

This results in the following

```
id=0&username=dat
```

I'd like a quick way to exclude `id` when I do this toJSON (does this exist w/ out writing it by hand?) Using jQuery 1.8+

Thank you in advance

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761424/convert-object-to-json-omitting-certain-private-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was really simple

```
var json_data = record.toJSON();
delete json_data.id;
var data = $.param(json_data);
```

Now instead of

```
id=0&username=dat
```

I now get

```
username=dat
```