# How delete a private property in a class?

Tags: typescript, data-modeling

I need some explanation about typescript class because I have something I didn't understand. Per example, I have a class "Car" with some properties :

```
export class Car {

    private _id: number;
    private _brand: string;
    private _model: string;

    constructor(car) {
        if (car) {
            this.id = car.id;
            this.brand = car.brand; // should be this.brand or this._brand ?
            this.model = car.model;
        }
    }

    set id(value: number) {
        this._id = value;
    }

    get id(): number {
        return this._id;
    }

    set brand(value: number) {
        this._brand = value;
    }

    get brand(): number {
        return this._brand;
    }

    set model(value: number) {
        this._model = value;
    }

    get model(): number {
        return this._model;
    }
}
```

I have to send this object to an API. This one accept "brand" and "model" and not "_brand" or "_model". So how can I send the good model to the API ?

So here what I have when I display the car object via a console.log :

Car { id: "1", brand: "Porsche", model: "Carrera", _id: "1", _brand: "Porsche", _model: "Carrera" }

If I delete "_brand", the "brand" value is undefined but I want to keep it.

```
delete myCar['_brand'];
console.log(myCar); // Car {_id:"1", "brand": undefined ...}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert object to JSON omitting certain (private) properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11761424/convert-object-to-json-omitting-certain-private-properties)

Comment: Yes you're right :) Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

private/public/protected only works within the typescript compiler, sending things over to "regular javascript" will still show everything in the object, including private variables.

To only send public variables, you'd have to create a seperate object that exludes the private variables.